# How can I describe the Any type in protobuf-net?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In google protobuf v3 there is the Any type that allows you to serialize a name/url identifying the message (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any, https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto).

Is it possible to describe this construct and have protobuf-net serialize/deserialize it? I need it to follow protobuf v3 standard, so DynamicType/bcl.NetObjectProxy is close, but not binary compatible.

If not, what is the best way to serialize objects with Any constructs using protobuf-net? I really don't want to switch to protobuf-csharp version.

Comment: FYI, I'm actively working on proto3 support and tooling updates currently; I would expect to see full `Any` support in the 2.3.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, `Any` can be treated as just:

```
[ProtoContract]
public sealed class Any {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public string type_url {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)] public byte[] value {get;set;}
}
```

From there, you could do a `switch` (or a dictionary lookup) on the url, load the value into a `MemoryStream`, and call back into protobuf-net. For serialization, the type url could perhaps be stored in an attribute against the type, but that is trickier fog deserialization. Maybe a string-to-Type dictionary and the non-generic API.

Comment: BTW, I'd be happy to consider adding `Any` to the library with helper methods etc, but I'd be interested in looking at what the right API is for resolving types from names. Not a trivial thing to unwrap, especially during deserialization (the serialization is pretty trivial)

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But I wanted protobuf-net to do the (de)serialization of the bytes. What I would really like in protobuf-net is to be able to override (de)serialization with something like an ITypeFormatter.[De]Serialize(Proto[Reader/Writer], object). It could be selected by attribute like Json.net JsonConverterAttribute and/or added dynamically to the model overriding the default. Then the user can control input/output 100%, locally implement [ProtoAny()] etc as shortcut for specific serializer.

Comment: Just to set the scene, the ultimate goal is to replace a proprietary binary serializer with protobuf/json for an asp.net 5 Web Api Websocket RPC. The use of Any is to be able to dynamically extend the WebSocket API surface w/ "plugins". Websocket Text/Bin mode will select between Json/Protobuf serializer. So I'm also going to do "protobuf canonical json" serialization and use GetProto<>() on this stuff to get the correct .proto file for other users not using C#. But I prefer the "code first" over .proto first, since it is hard to get good code from a generic .proto file.

Comment: @maloo Question: do you need support for other (non-protobuf-net) libraries? Because: protobuf-net had an implementation of what you describe a long time ago... `AsDynamic`, IIRC (can't remember whether that is on the contract, the member, or both). It is implemented differently, however, and is not directly compatible with `Any`

Comment: Other protobuf libraries? If so, no. Unless of course I can't get GetProto<> to generate the Any contract, but keep the member type of System.Object or similar. It sounds like it would take some work on protobuf-net. So I might just go with a simple protobuf reader/writer + T4 code+proto gen from model types. That is what I did for the old stuff, and is very flexible, fast, but of course more code to write and maintain.

Comment: I pick this as answer, since it would technically work. But I will probably take a different route. I still have to do similar stuff for the JSON serialization, and with a reader/writer + code gen there is not much extra work.
Would be nice to get better code gen / mixin support in VS/C# than T4 though. I'm very envious of D mixins :)